# SplashScreen java change alpha

Tags: java, animation, png, splash-screen

I am looping through a few png's to create an animation for a java splashscreen.

I start the animation using this

```
java -splash:images/anim.png SplashDemo
```

and use the pngs inside the class . You can find the class here- http://pastebin.com/UWm25QfY

My only problem is whatever alpha I choose to start the animation using anim.png is final and is being overwritten for all the pngs later

I tried the AlphaComposite.Clear,Src,SrcOver but nothing worked. If I load a png iniatially with 0 opacity then the entire animation disappears. Could anyone tell me how to get rid of this?

Comment: Is the linked code the only code you are using or have you altered it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer http://pastebin.com/UWm25QfY I modified a bit sorry i updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem you are facing has to do with the fact that the `Graphics` context you are painting is never actually "cleaned" or "rest" between updates.  Which is a pain, I know, but there it is.

About the only choice you have is to actually reset the output on each cycle, before you paint the next image.

Lucky for use, `SplashScreen` actually provides the `URL` to background image.  This allows us to load the image ourselves and repaint onto the surface as we need.

You should also make all best efforts to restore the `Graphics` context to the state you found it (except for what ever you painted on it of course).  This can be eaisly done by making a copy of the graphics state before you paint to it...

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
// Do you're painting here...
// Release the state when you're done.
g2d.dispose();
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.SplashScreen;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SplashScreen100 extends Frame implements ActionListener {

    static ArrayList<Image> imgs;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage background;

    protected void renderSplashFrame(Graphics2D g, Image bg) {

        // Get the splash screen size...
        Dimension size = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen().getSize();
        int width = size.width;
        int height = size.height;

        // Center the image within the splash screen
        int x = (width - bg.getWidth(null)) / 2;
        int y = (height - bg.getHeight(null)) / 2;
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        // Draw the background
        g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        // Apply alpha composite
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
        // Draw the image...
        g2d.drawImage(bg, x, y, null);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public SplashScreen100() {
        super("SplashScreen demo");
        final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
        if (splash == null) {
            System.out.println("SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null");
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
        if (g == null) {
            System.out.println("g is null");
            return;
        }

        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(splash.getImageURL());

            for (Image img : imgs) {
                renderSplashFrame(g, img);
                splash.update();
                // I put this in to slow the updates down...
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SplashScreen100.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        splash.close();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration config = device.getDefaultConfiguration();

        imgs = new ArrayList<Image>();
        for (File file : new File("\path\to\images").listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) {
                try {
                    Image buffy = ImageIO.read(file);
                    imgs.add(buffy);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        SplashScreen100 test = new SplashScreen100();
    }

}
```

**Updated with a different approach**

Basically, as the size of the image increases, the speed of the update decreases.  Instead, I would simply create your own so you can better control the update process.

This uses an a `JWindow` as the base window and a customised `JPanel` as the main display.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import static splashscreen.MySplashScreen.createCompatibleImage;
import static splashscreen.MySplashScreen.getGraphicsConfiguration;

public class DifferentSplashScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DifferentSplashScreen();
    }

    public DifferentSplashScreen() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JWindow frame = new JWindow();
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new SplashPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SplashPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;
        private List<BufferedImage> frames;
        private int frameIndex;
        private BufferedImage currentFrame;

        public SplashPane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\shane\\Dropbox\\MegaTokyo\\2005-09-29-3957.jpeg"));
                frames = new ArrayList<>(40);
                List<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<>(20);
                for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
                    try {
                        BufferedImage buffy = ImageIO.read(new File(index + ".png"));
                        images.add(createCompatibleImage(buffy));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                frames.addAll(images);
                Collections.reverse(images);
                frames.addAll(images);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            final Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (frameIndex >= frames.size()) {
                        frameIndex = 0;
                    }
                    currentFrame = frames.get(frameIndex);
                    frameIndex++;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);

                if (currentFrame != null) {

                    x = (getWidth() - currentFrame.getWidth()) / 2;
                    y = (getHeight() - currentFrame.getHeight()) / 2;
                    g2d.drawImage(currentFrame, x, y, this);

                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage master) {
        BufferedImage img = createCompatibleImage(master, master.getWidth(), master.getHeight());
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(master, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image,
            int width, int height) {
        return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, image.getTransparency());
    }
}
```

It also converts all the images to "device compatiable" images, meaning they should render faster as their color pallette's don't need to be converted on the fly.

The background image was 1563x1250 and the face images are 300x300 (with varying alpha levels).

Use this example, I got a steadily update without issue, using the same images with the `SplashScreen`, it was pretty horrible...

Comment: Won't this screw up the framerate ?? I will try it tomoro

Comment: When I loop over the images the framerate I get is going down sometimes. Any suggestions to improve the frame rate. I think you solved the alpha problem thank you very much

Comment: You currently actually have no frame rate control at all.  I put in a small delay because it just zipped through my images in under a second :P.  Try using a `Thread.sleep` to adjust the time between updates (40 milliseconds is 25fps)

Comment: Actually i cant use gif's because of the alpha problem .. I have png which are 1280x720 and once I load 10 of them the frame rate drops to 2 fps

Comment: I spoke too soon even with your code I still have the same problem. You used a gif and that is why it worked for you. Just use a png with very low opacity, your animation will disappear

Comment: Are you sure the initial png has 0 opacity. because I just tried it again :(

Comment: I'm doing inline alphaing at the paint stage

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FY5w0AX.png try with this when you invoke and let me know if it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39028/discussion-between-pavan-k-and-madprogrammer)

Comment: I had a quick look at the alphering (generated 20 images ranging from 0.0f-1.0f) and it did render, but the output is less than optimal.

Comment: I might have miscommunicated. The alpha of the png you use for anim.png in java -splash:images/anim.png SplashDemo is being used. The png of the folder are rendering fine. If you set the alpha of anim.png  to 0 then nothing is rendering

Comment: So it's the background image that is alphed? What about the oth images?

Comment: other images disappear if the alpha of the background image is 0

Comment: I will try ur neww method

Comment: Personally, if I was trying to produce a transparent splash screen, I'd use a transparent window...but that's because I don't like the splash screen API ;)